# Why is list+set method of making a list unique faster than dictionary keys method?

Tags: python, timeit

Here is a sample of timeit trial for the same:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = """
... from random import randint
... rand_list = [randint(0,10) for i in range(0,10000)]
... """

>>> timeit.Timer('list(set(rand_list))', setup=setup).repeat(5, 1000)
[0.17256593704223633, 0.17117094993591309, 0.17115998268127441, 0.17191100120544434, 0.17226791381835938]
>>> timeit.Timer('{ x:True for x in rand_list}.keys()', setup=setup).repeat(5, 1000)
[0.4490840435028076, 0.44455599784851074, 0.442918062210083, 0.4430229663848877, 0.44559407234191895]
```

As you can see, the list(set(MY_LIST)) method is approximately 2.5 times faster than dictionary method, the result is similar for smaller lists or bigger lists.

Can anyone please explain why this is so i.e. the difference in functionality of execution of both these steps in terms of time complexity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running a Python loop over 10000 items in your second test, in a dictionary comprehension; it is that loop that slows it down.

You could try [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) instead:

```
dict.fromkeys(rand_list).keys()
```

This creates a dictionary from the `rand_list` values with all values set to `None`.

This is only *slightly* slower now:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from random import randint
>>> rand_list = [randint(0,10) for i in range(0,10000)]
>>> timeit.Timer('list(set(rand_list))', setup='from __main__ import rand_list').repeat(5, 1000)
[0.1437511444091797, 0.13837504386901855, 0.13841795921325684, 0.1395130157470703, 0.1474599838256836]
>>> timeit.Timer('dict.fromkeys(rand_list).keys()', setup='from __main__ import rand_list').repeat(5, 1000)
[0.18216991424560547, 0.17930316925048828, 0.18064308166503906, 0.17971301078796387, 0.17820501327514648]
```

That's to be expected; a `dict()` slightly more work as you track keys and values, as opposed to just keys in a set.